# Feed GNU parallel with an array?

Tags: arrays, bash, gnu-parallel

How to feed a command in GNU parallel with an array? For example, I have this array:

```
x=(0.1 0.2 0.5)
```

and now I want to feed it to some command in `parallel`

```
parallel echo ::: $x
```

This does not work. It is feeding all the arguments to a single call, since it prints

```
0.1 0.2 0.5
```

instead of

```
0.1
0.2
0.5
```

which is the output of

```
parallel echo ::: 0.1 0.2 0.5
```

How can I do it right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to provide all the elements in the array use:

```
parallel echo ::: ${x[@]}
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use `"${x[@]}"` in case any array elements contain spaces in future, e.g. `x=("0.1 + 6" "0.2 - b" "0.5 + a")`

Answer (score 5):

From: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

*EXAMPLE: Using shell variables
When using shell variables you need to quote them correctly as they may otherwise be split on spaces.*

*Notice the difference between:*

```
V=("My brother's 12\" records are worth <\$\$\$>"'!' Foo Bar)
parallel echo ::: ${V[@]} # This is probably not what you want
```

*and:*

```
V=("My brother's 12\" records are worth <\$\$\$>"'!' Foo Bar)
parallel echo ::: "${V[@]}"
```

*When using variables in the actual command that contains special characters (e.g. space) you can quote them using '"$VAR"' or using "'s and -q:*

```
V="Here  are  two "
parallel echo "'$V'" ::: spaces
parallel -q echo "$V" ::: spaces
```